# Laravel Load View take too much time

Tags: performance, laravel, xampp, loading

i don't know what happen. its not happen before. every button that will call route will need about 25-30 sec. really slow. and it happen to all my web project. even all project doesn't have relation each other.

i guest this is XAMPP issue or composer so i reinstall it. and browser too. but no effect. is i doing something wrong? i have do view:clear and Cache:clear. still took too much time. it didn't happen in other computer. just my laptop. Please give me some suggest what should i do

Update:
I find something that slow loading is happen when my laptop wifi is enable or connected to some wifi. any idea?

Comment: It could just be your computer running slowly?

Comment: Prefer re-formatting... lol .... Not but seriously... How much RAM does your laptop have? Specs please? And can you go to **Task Manager** and check how much memory **php.exe** is utilizing?

Comment: i have i7 skylake with 8 ram and 4 vga gtx 940. i think it is high enough for web development

Answer (score 1):

This will sound stupid but the trouble is really the wifi connection. i know it when start using second laptop in the same connection but trouble is same. and i try using laptop with different wifi connection. i dont know why because i think i run it localy without relation with wifi/internet. but when i disable wifi it run fast like usual. so i try disconnecting with current wifi connection(the trouble connection) with other conection. i try it and run well. and then i reconnect with my wifi that make slow loading and... done. just it. change other wifi and reconnect back. is it laravel bug or happen somthing to my router? dont know. hope this help someone that stuck with this funny trap
cheers!